# Full authentication error on localhost:8080 but not on localhost:3000

Tags: spring, reactjs, spring-boot, react-native, http-post

I got a strange behavior when developing with Spring Boot (back end) and React (front end). React and Spring boot are both running on localhost:8080.

When I'm sending a POST request on localhost:8080 from React to Spring Boot, I got this ERROR in Spring Boot:

```
2018-07-17 21:39:27.803 ERROR 8676 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.s.jwt.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint      : Responding with unauthorized error. Message - Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

*Firefox output on port 8080*
[image: Firefox Port 8080]

When I'm sending the same POST request from localhost:3000 (React development build) to Spring Boot on localhost:8080, I got not ERROR!

*Firefox output on port 3000*
[image]

I also got no errors when sending the POST request with the software POSTMAN.

github: https://github.com/The-Taskmanager/SelfServiceWebwizard

**The post request**

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signin', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Accept': '*/*'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        "usernameOrEmail": username,
        "password": password
    })
}).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        console.log("Authorization header console.log: " + response.headers.get("Authorization"));
        let token = response.headers.get("Authorization");
        this.setToken(token != null ? token : '');
    }
).catch(error => console.error(error));
```

}

**The mapping in Spring Boot**

```
  @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        loginRequest.getUsernameOrEmail(),
                        loginRequest.getPassword()
                )
        );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        String jwt = tokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.add("Authorization", new JwtAuthenticationResponse(jwt).getAccessToken());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).build();

    }
```

**Spring Boot Security Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    /**
     * Loads user related data .
     */
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    /**
     * Handles exceptions from unauthorized access
     */
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    /**
     * Returns new JwtAuthenticationFilter
     *
     * @return new JwtAuthenticationFilter
     */
    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authentication manager. Sets authentication menchanism.
     *
     * @param authenticationManagerBuilder authentication manager builder
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    /**
     * Authentication manager to authenticate a user
     *
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a bcrypt password encoder. Bcrypt is a hash function for passwords so the passwords are not saved in
     * clear text.
     *
     * @return bcrypt password encoder
     */
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    /**
     * Creates protection rules for specific paths.
     *
     * @param http security type
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/",
                        "/index",
                        "/index.html",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/fetch")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/signin")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/user/checkUsernameAvailability", "/api/user/checkEmailAvailability")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/users/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

        // add own filters
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    /**
     * Handles the cross-origin ressource sharing.
     *
     * @return CORS configuration
     */
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
# search path for static content (for react)
spring.resources.static-locations=file:build,classpath:/public,classpath:/static
# path to database file
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/h2db/h2_database;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
# database platform
spring.datasource.platform=h2
# data base drive
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
# JSON web token secret
app.jwtSecret= fsiuhfsdihfdspsfdhspiufdhpvc
# 0.5 days
app.jwtExpirationInMs = 43200000
# activate to persist data, otherwise the data will be deleted on restart
# spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

**-- UPDATE --**

I don't understand but it seems that the API ERROR is related to the access on the browser's console! I removed the console.log methods from my POST request and the API ERROR was gone.

This was my request method in React:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signin', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Accept': '*/*'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        "usernameOrEmail": username,
        "password": password
    })
}).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        console.log("Authorization header console.log: " + response.headers.get("Authorization"));
        let token = response.headers.get("Authorization");
        this.setToken(token != null ? token : '');
    }
).catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Remove console.log methods:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signin', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Accept': '*/*'

        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "usernameOrEmail": username,
            "password": password
        })
    }).then(response => {
            let token = response.headers.get("Authorization");
            this.setToken(token != null ? token : '');
        }
    ).catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

**So does anybody know if there is a restriction on the browser's console and how to disable this?**

Comment: At first look seems to be CORS related issue, are you sure you have it properly configured? [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: @Xarvalus Yeah i thought so too but strangely enough the error appears when I'm accessing from the same origin (localhost:8080) and not from another origin (localhost:3000). I configured CORS at the bottom of codesnippet "Spring Boot SecurityConfig". I permitted all origins with .applyPermitDefaultValues(), i think

Comment: Try adding `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"` to the `package.json` file and then call the api with `fetch('/api/auth/signin', {...`

Comment: @GuisongHe Done, nothing changed.

Comment: @taskmanager I check out your project and add the proxy to the package.json then the response has changed to `{"timestamp":"2018-07-18T07:52:11.856+0000","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Sorry, You're not authorized to access this resource.","path":"/api/auth/signin"}`. Do you restart your react?

Comment: @GuisongHe Yes, I rebuilt React but nothing changed. What would be the reason for setting a proxy?

Comment: @Taskmanager what's the api response after you setting the proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself.

The API error didn't happen because of a restricted console access but on restricted React ressources. Actually only one React ressource was restricted: **/static/js/main.RANDOM_CODE.js**

Firefox gave me the hint with the ressource address and 401 ERORR:
[image]

So I've added **"/build/static/js/*.js"** to antMatchers in configure(HttpSecurity http) in SecurityConfig:

```
            .antMatchers("/",
                    "/index",
                    "/index.html",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/**/*.png",
                    "/**/*.gif",
                    "/**/*.svg",
                    "/**/*.jpg",
                    "/**/*.html",
                    "/**/*.css",
                    "/**/*.map",
                    "/**/*.js",
                    "/build/static/js/*.js")
```

If you ask me why this only happened on localhost:8080 (on same origin), I guess, that the path to the main.[...].js is different.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new port for the spring in application.properties file like  server.port=8081 then try to access it via that port

Comment: Thanks but problem still exists